# Tree in a treenode

Tags: tikz-pgf, trees

Is there a way to insert a Tree (with depth 1) in a Tree-node? Which package to use and how to accomplish that?

Comment: Can you elaborate that? Do you mean a tree as a new object inside a tree node? Or a tree merged into an existing node?

Comment: A tree as a new object inside a node. I played with the tikz-package regarding that, but failed to do it and could not find any good example. Thank you.

Comment: Perhaps a picture of what you are trying to achieve would help us understand what you want

Answer (score 3):

One thing you could try is to put a new tikzpicture inside the node, and create the tree in that.  You would have to figure out the anchors, though.

Comment: Never nest `tikzpicture`s!

Comment: @cfr: why?  Do you have any reference in the pgf manual or elsewhere that says so?  What kind of trouble am I inviting if I do nest them? And, finally, what would then be the correct way to achieve what the OP wants?

Comment: There are several questions on this site explaining why doing this means trouble. In very simple cases, you may get lucky but you should expect it to break (now or with a later update or whatever). If you put the inner one in a save box first, You can include it into another one with `\usebox`, for example, because the content is then typeset earlier when the box is saved (I think).